# Установка произвольной позиции трекера OxyPlot WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, graph, oxyplot

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с проблемой - при малом размере окна, трекер графика выходит за его пределы. Проблема видна на прикрепленном изображении. Может быть, имеются какие-либо способы выводить трекер в определенной позиции, независимо от просматриваемой точки (самый предпочтительный вариант), или эту проблему можно решить иными путями? Спасибо.

[image: визуальное отражение проблемы]

Comment: В какую позицию вы хотите поместить трекер?

Comment: Почему бы просто не запрещать минимизировать до таких размеров?

Comment: @Ev_Hyper разместить можно где-нибудь справа внизу, ближе к контуру окна.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задать внешний вид и расположение трекера можно переопределив `DefaultTrackerTemplate`.

Простой набросок - направление в какую сторону смотреть:

```
<oxy:Plot Title="">
    <oxy:Plot.DefaultTrackerTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Canvas>
                <TextBlock Canvas.Left="0"
                           Canvas.Top="0"
                           Margin="10"
                           Background="LightYellow"
                           Padding="5"
                           Text="{Binding}" />
            </Canvas>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </oxy:Plot.DefaultTrackerTemplate>
```

Результат будет следующим

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

За то, как будут отображены данные отвечает свойство `TrackerFormatString`. Для каждой серии они разные, узнать какой параметр за что отвечает вы также можете в документации.

Например для [LineSeries](http://docs.oxyplot.org/en/latest/models/series/LineSeries.html#tracker):

> ```
> {0} - заголовок текущей серии
> {1} - название оси X
> {2} - значение X
> {3} - название оси Y
> {4} - значение Y
> ```

Конкретный пример

```
<oxy:LineSeries Title="Sin (x)"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Points}"
                TrackerFormatString="X = {2:00}, Y = {4:00}"
                Color="Red" />
```

Также примеры кастомизации шаблона трекера можно посмотреть [в примерах](https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/blob/fe84b034c1105fd0cd679d8cedd88d9c20fde417/Source/Examples/WPF/WpfExamples/Examples/CustomTrackerDemo/MainWindow.xaml) к проекту на GitHub.

Подробнее о возможностях трекера можно прочесть в [документации](http://docs.oxyplot.org/en/latest/views/tracker.html)

Comment: благодарю, с позицией разобрался. Теперь пытаюсь внести в TrackerFormatString строку с временем, но она почему-то не обновляется динамически

Comment: @SNMetamorph чуть больше подробностей напишите, нужно хотя-бы несколько тестовых значений

Comment: На [картинке](http://imgur.com/XPhGlsR), в трекере, после буквы T отображается координата X точки, в моем коде сделано так - координата каждой последующей точки на 1 больше чем прошлая, то есть самая первая точка на графике имеет координату 0, вторая - 1 и так далее. Но я вместо этих координат хочу вывести в трекере время появления каждой точки на графике, пробовал редактировать TrackerFormatString - не выходит, судя по всему там можно оперировать только лишь аргументами предоставленными библиотекой.  
Должно получится примерно это:
T: 19:42
S: *какое-то число*

Comment: @SNMetamorph тогда вам нужно и в модели сохранять время получения, или сохранять только стартовое время и уже маппить результат с его учетом. Но первый вариант проще и в данном случае кажется более логичным